# R: Calculate percent of column values in a Time Series

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Connection    Account.Created.Month
Wired        12
Wired        12       
Wireless     13
Wired        13
```

I want to create a plot that shows for each month what the percent of connections were Wired vs Wireless. For example with the data above it would be 100% Wired for month 12, and 50% Wired for month 13.

Here is my plotting code:

```
ea1wirelessUsed <- aggregate(data_ea1$Connection, list(Mon = data_ea1$Account.Created.Month), mean)

pea1 <- ggplot(ea1wirelessUsed, aes(x=Mon, y=x, fill=Mon)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ylab("Wired vs Wireless") +
  xlab("Time")
grid.arrange(pea1)
```

I'm not sure what to pass in for the x value to show the aggregated % of wired vs wireless connection.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `tidyverse` package. I made a `count` to get the data in the proper format to make the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_ea1 %>%
  #Group by both vars
  group_by(Connection,Accoun.Created.Month) %>%
  #Count the number of connections by grouping variables
  count() %>%
  #Make the plot
  ggplot(aes(x=Accoun.Created.Month, 
             y=n, 
             fill=Connection)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(y = "Percent", x = "Month")
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: That is excellent. However, I don't understand why you needed to "complete" the data.

Comment: Indeed, the "complete" is not necessary. It works fine without it. I am editing the answer to eliminate it.